# Which library provides the functionality to send emails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Which library provides the functionality to send emails?

```
  1)  Net::POPMail
  2)  Internet::PMTP
  3)  Net::SMTP
  4)  Internet::SMTP
```

Comment: Looks like you tried to attempt oDesk rails evaluation test

Comment: The next time someone posts a question that looks like homework, I'm going to deliberately and hilariously give them the wrongest answer I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Net::SMTP is the library in standard ruby to do this. If you're in a Rails app, as your tag implies, you can also use ActionMailer to provide view-like templates for outgoing emails and so forth.  The [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) for it is marked as work-in-progress but probably still useful.